# Insert only a record using CrudRepository

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

When save from `CrudRepository` in Spring data is called, it either updates the existing record in the database or creates a new record if the id for that record is null/blank.

I have a app which inserts and updates records in a table where primary key is a `String`, so not increment, but the value stored in that column is `Integer`. So the app gets the `max(last_insert_id(string))` and increments it for the new record and saves it to the database. There is another app which is doing the same process and in some cases, the data is getting overwritten.

So when using `CrudRepository`, if I can only insert the record instead of updating it, that should help in resolving the issue. How can i create only a new record using `CrudRepository`, is there any built in support for it ?

Comment: You are aware that when using multiple applications for the same database, the strategy for determining the primary key is a pretty bad one?

Comment: @M.Deinum I know it is a bad strategy, but it is something I inherited and cannot make a change because there are lot of other apps using that, so I have to live with it for now.

Comment: Instead of working around JPA (not necessarily Spring Data JPA) work with it. Create a custom generator for the ids which contains the logic you are executing now. Instead of doing it yourself in the application, that way the detection logic in the app will work (more) reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Better use a custom sequence generator for your scenario.

https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-implement-a-custom-string-based-sequence-identifier-generator-with-hibernate/